# Problema con Serializacion

Tags: java, jframe

Tengo una clase serializada la cual tiene varios atributos estos son estáticos ya que necesito estar modificandolos, el problema es que despues de 
serializar y guardar los datos ,al volverlos a leer todos los atributos quedan con su valor por defecto, ¿De que manera puedo hacer que esos atributos tomen el valor de los datos guardados anteriormente serializados?

**Aqui la clase serializada:**

```
package Parqueadero;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Informes implements Serializable {

    //Suma total de dinero
    private static double sdinerot = 0;

    //Suma de dinero por tipo de  clientes 
    private static double sdineroTA = 0;
    private static double sdineroTB = 0;
    private static double sdineroTC = 0;

    //total de clientes segun su tipo 
    private static int tCA = 0, tCB = 0, tCC = 0;

    //Suma de dinero por tipo de vehiculo
    private static double sdinerocarro = 0;
    private static double sdinerocamioneta = 0;
    private static double sdinerobus = 0;
    private static double sdineromoto = 0;

    public double getSdinerot() {
        return sdinerot;
    }

    public void setSdinerot(double total) {
        sdinerot = sdinerot + total;

    }

    public double getSdineroTA() {
        return sdineroTA;
    }

    public void setSdineroTA(double sdineroTA) {
        this.sdineroTA = this.sdineroTA + sdineroTA;
    }

    public double getSdineroTB() {
        return sdineroTB;
    }

    public void setSdineroTB(double sdineroTB) {
        this.sdineroTB = this.sdineroTB + sdineroTB;
    }

    public double getSdineroTC() {
        return sdineroTC;
    }

    public void setSdineroTC(double sdineroTC) {
        this.sdineroTC = this.sdineroTC + sdineroTC;
    }

    public int gettCA() {
        return tCA;
    }

    public void setcCA() {
        tCA++;
    }

    public int gettCB() {
        return tCB;
    }

    public void setcCB() {
        tCB++;
    }

    public int gettCC() {
        return tCC;
    }

    public void setcCC() {
        tCC++;
    }

    public double getSdinerocarro() {
        return sdinerocarro;
    }

    public void setSdinerocarro(double sdinerocarro) {
        this.sdinerocarro = this.sdinerocarro + sdinerocarro;
    }

    public double getSdinerocamioneta() {
        return sdinerocamioneta;
    }

    public void setSdinerocamioneta(double sdinerocamioneta) {
        this.sdinerocamioneta = this.sdinerocamioneta + sdinerocamioneta;
    }

    public double getSdinerobus() {
        return sdinerobus;
    }

    public void setSdinerobus(double sdinerobus) {
        this.sdinerobus = this.sdinerobus + sdinerobus;
    }

    public double getSdineromoto() {
        return sdineromoto;
    }

    public void setSdineromoto(double sdineromoto) {
        this.sdineromoto = this.sdineromoto + sdineromoto;
    }

    public double getPromedioClienteA() {
        if (tCA == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return (sdineroTA / tCA);
    }

    public double getPromedioClienteB() {
        if (tCB == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return (sdineroTB / tCB);
    }

    public double getPromedioClienteC() {
        if (tCC == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return (sdineroTC / tCC);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No los hagas estáticos. Realmente no tienes ningún motivo para hacerlos estáticos, puesto que los métodos que acceden a ellos no lo son y, por tanto, significa que estás creando una instancia (un objeto) de esa clase para trabajar.

Comment: Tengo un JFrame aparte donde nececito si ó si mostrar esos datos, entonces si no los pongo estáticos  todos esos datos me los muestra con el valor por default

Comment: Algo estás haciendo mal entonces, crea el objeto, rellena los datos y pásaselo al JFrame